# Installing Gearman on Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS Codename Hardy

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install gearman on ubuntu 8.04 and this are the options i have.

1.Install package dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
sudo apt-get install libcloog-ppl0
```

and make gearman from source

2.apt-add from a ppa but <del>i guess 8.04 is too ancient</del> so that might not work

The first option almost works but

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libcloog-ppl0
```

give

```
E: Couldn't find package
```

I have done some searching on

> packages dot ubuntu dot com

but `libboost-all-dev` and `libcloog-ppl0` are not available for hardy.

What other option do i have to install the missing packages?.

Comment: I have successfully installed it on hardy.I shall add the answer after one day.

Comment: you can post an answer straight away. The time limit only applies to *accepting* your own answer by clicking the green tick icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install gearman you are going to need this

https://launchpad.net/~drizzle-developers/+archive/ppa

and

https://launchpad.net/~gearman-developers/+archive/ppa

To get the deb entries and the fingerprint for the urls given,visit the links and click to toggle **'Technical details about this PPA'**

Run this command with the fingerprint obtained from the said links

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys NUMBER
```

Run the above command for the two links given above.

do an update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install gearman

```
sudo apt-get install gearman-job-server libgearman2 libgearman-dev gearman-tools

sudo pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/gearman-0.8.0
```

Add the generated php extension - `extension=gearman.so` to your `php cli ini` and `php5 ini`.

**Note**

- I was unable to install the latest pecl package for gearman and only version 0.8.0 worked.
- I did not have to upgrade any package on 8.04 for this to work.
- I have `php5-dev` installed